# GetAccessControl() on a directory using Powershell returns no data

Tags: powershell, acl, directory, powershell-1.0

I have a directory whose name contains square brackets, making handling it in Powershell a little problematic. I've seen advice that to get the ACL of the directory, you should use the `GetAccessControl()` method of `DirectoryInfo` instead of using the cmdlet `Get-Acl`.

Unfortunately, using `GetAccessControl()` is not returning any results for any directory. See my script below.

```
$filename = "C:\somefolder"
$di = get-item $filename
$di | get-acl    # this returns the correct ACL data as expected
$di.GetAccessControl()   # this shows an empty ACL (see below output)
```

What I mean by an empty ACL is this:

```
Path      Owner      Access
----      -----      ------
```

The only way I've found to get an instance of $di with a directory name which contains square brackets is to escape the brackets with double back-ticks

```
$filename = "C:\some``[folder``]withsquarebrackets"
```

If I do this and then execute `$di = get-item $filename`, `$di` shows that it contains details on the specified folder. But in this case, different results are returned by the remaining two lines:

```
$di | get-acl     # does nothing, doesn't even show an empty ACL
$di.GetAccessControl()   # shows an empty ACL as seen above
```

Can anyone explain how I can reliably get the ACL for an enumeration of folders, some of which contain square brackets in their names?

**Update 2012-02-23 16:31Z**
After Andy Arismendi reported it worked for him, I established that GetAccessControl() seems to work fine on Powershell 2. The affected machine runs Powershell 1. Any ideas how to resolve this using Powershell 1?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me although the `Path` property is null.

```
$f = Get-Item 'C:\some `[folder`]'
$f.GetAccessControl()
$f.GetAccessControl().Access
```

Comment: Interesting. I've tried it on another machine and it works. The original machine is running Powershell v1, and the one that works has Powershell v2. On both both machines, if the filename contains a square bracket, piping $f to the Get-Acl cmdlet does not return a result.

Comment: I was clearly wrong about the double back-tick though... single back-tick in the filename produces the same result.

Comment: @RichardFawcett Check out this [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/544237/filename-bracket-problem) report. Someone posted a workaround, I added it to my answer, give it a try.

Comment: @RichardFawcett Nevermind just tried it out and it didn't work... I removed it from my answer.

Comment: In 2020, `getaccesscontrol()` does its job still brilliant. Be aware to import the `ntfssecurity` modul from [here](https://github.com/raandree/NTFSSecurity). Why is `path`empty?

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets problem is because the square brackets are "globbing" wildcards.  You can avoid all the escaping by using the -literalpath parameter:

```
$di = get-item -literalpath C:\some[folder]withsquarebrackets
$di.getaccesscontrol()
```

Unfortunately they did not include a -literpath parameter for get-acl, so you're  stuck with doing the get-item, then using the getaccesscontrol() method of that to get the access list. Get-Acl does have a -literalpath parameter in V3.

Comment: +1 This really helped.  In my case the invalid path was returned by `FileSystemObject.GetFolder.SubFolders`.  So my script runs for a few minutes, then suddenly breaks for no reason. Yet another MS caveat kicked it in the back.  While there are always good reasons for wildcards, this path has been returned by Windows, the script did not know it before.